# Implement Edit in liferay portlet

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

I'm developing a liferay portlet. Here is my code in jsp file:

```
<table class="DDGridView">
<tr class="td">
    <td class="th">Complex Name</td>
    <td class="th">City</td>
    <td class="th">Status</td>
</tr>
<%
    Complex complex;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < complexList.size(); i++)
    {
        complex = (Complex)complexList.get(i);
%>
        <tr class="td">
            <td><%=complex.complexName %></td>
            <td><%=complex.complexCity %></td>
            <%
                if(complex.isActive == 1)
                {
            %>              
                    <td class="th">Active</td>
            <%
                }
                else
                {
            %>
                    <td>Not Active</td>
            <%
                }
            %>
            <td><a href="<%=prepareEditComplexURL%>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
<%
    }
%>  
</table>
```

When user clicks on Edit url, I want to send the selected row items to the portlet class. But I don't know how to do that. How can I do that?

Comment: can you elaborate what do you mean by "selected row items". How are you preparing the `prepareEditComplexURL` or do you want help in preparing this URL itself?

Comment: By clicking Edit execution goes to a method in portlet class. Inside that method I need to know complexName, complexCity and status of the row whose Edit button was clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your comment it seems you need help in constructing URLs.

So, you can construct the URL inside the `for` loop like:

If you want to use these details to do some database operations like `update` or `insert`

```
<portlet:actionURL var="preparedEditComplexURL">
    <portlet:param name="complexName" value="<%=complex.complexName %>" />
    <portlet:param name="complexCity " value="<%=complex.complexCity %>" />
    <portlet:param name="status " value="<%=complex.isActive %>" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

Or if you want to render (or show) some page depending on these fields then use Render URL, like this:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="preparedEditComplexURL">
    <portlet:param name="complexName" value="<%=complex.complexName %>" />
    <portlet:param name="complexCity " value="<%=complex.complexCity %>" />
    <portlet:param name="status " value="<%=complex.isActive %>" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

Also it would help if you can refer some concepts regarding portletURLs and how to use them. There are good tutorials available and also `Portlets in Action` is a good book regarding almost all the concepts of portlet development in one place.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Prakash K answer it's really good! Just adding one thing that can be useful. 
When you create a portlet action url, you can specifiy a name attribute like this

```
<portlet:actionURL name="preparedEditComplex" var="preparedEditComplexURL">
    <portlet:param name="complexName" value="<%=complex.complexName %>" />
    <portlet:param name="complexCity " value="<%=complex.complexCity %>" />
    <portlet:param name="status " value="<%=complex.isActive %>" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

So that in your portlet class you can call your method like this:

## Liferay 6.x

```
public preparedEditComplex(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) {
    //Your implementation
    ...
}
```

## Liferay 5.2

```
@ProcessAction(name="preparedEditComplex")
public preparedEditComplex(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) {
    //Your implementation
    ...
}
```

This way you can write cleaner and more readble code. :)

Cheers